# At which location (path) does visual studio 2019 creates *.csproj.user file?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, file-location, csproj-user

What is the location of Visual studio 2019 created *.csproj.user file? I searched it in user appdata folder, but I couldn't find any. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of a the `.csproj.user` file should be in the same directory as the projects `.csproj` file.  By default, this is the folder for the project:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer with screenshot. I use visual studio 2019 v16.11.2. I don't find the .csproj.user file in project directory. I assume that all the project settings are stored in .csproj file and no user specific project settings are configured.

Comment: @Pradeep perhaps you do not have any user specific settings created yet.  Here something easy you can try - in solution explorer, [click the show all files button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFHAy.png), then save all files of the solution (CTRL + Shift + S).  Then check the project directory again.